# How to dynamically import modules with exec

Tags: python, exec

Now I want to built a function get_doc( ) which can get the **doc** of the module
Here's the code

```
def get_doc(module):
    exec "import module"
    print module.__doc__
```

And the information returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    get_doc(sys)
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're importing `"module"` instead of the specified module, and you didn't put the name `module` anywhere. A stupid fix to this would be to always using `exec`

```
def get_doc(module):
    exec "import {}".format(module)
    exec "print {}.__doc__".format(module)"
```

But instead of `exec`, i would advise you to use the `__import__` function:

```
def get_doc(module):
    module = __import__(module)
    print module.__doc__
```

Which allows more flexibility, and you can modify, use module as you wanted.

Comment: Exactly. It would be difficult to control

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
get_doc(sys)
```

python will not be able to recognize `sys`. The actual way to do what you are trying to do would be to

1. pass the module name as a string parameter
2. use `__import__` function to load the module, like this

   ```
   def get_doc(module):
       mod = __import__(module)
       print mod.__doc__

   get_doc("sys")
   ```

**Note:** I am not in favor of executing dynamic code in programs, but if you must use `exec` to solve this problem read [this](http://www.codekoala.com/posts/security-and-pythons-exec/) and have a basic understanding about the security implications and then look at aIKid's solution.

Comment: But I just want to use the exec, how about that way?

Comment: @Dergum Why? Is there any specific reason? I normally dont suggest to use dynamic execution of code, which is actually done by `exec`.

Comment: Agree with @thefourtheye, you can get tangled to an unnecessary mess. Executing your code dynamically is a bad idea, even if you know what you're doing.